# How to write XSLT for Converting XML to JSON?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have the following XML File as input and want an JSON output using  XSLT mapping. How can I design my XSLT file?

**XML Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SyncItemMaster versionID="2.14.0" releaseID="9.2"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.14.0/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncItemMaster.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
    <ApplicationArea>
        <Sender>
            <LogicalID>lid://infor.ln.ln_1100</LogicalID>
            <ComponentID>erp</ComponentID>
            <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
        </Sender>
        <CreationDateTime>2020-06-16T11:00:16Z</CreationDateTime>
        <BODID>infor-nid:infor:1100::11064973:?ItemMaster&verb=Sync</BODID>
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <Sync>
            <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
            <AccountingEntityID>1100</AccountingEntityID>
            <LocationID/>
            <ActionCriteria>
                <ActionExpression actionCode="Change"/>
            </ActionCriteria>
        </Sync>
        <ItemMaster>
            <ItemMasterHeader>
                <ItemID>
                    <ID variationID="4241287" lid="lid://infor.ln.ln_1100" accountingEntity="1100">11064973</ID>
                </ItemID>
                <DisplayID>11064973</DisplayID>
                <GTIN/>
                <ServiceIndicator>false</ServiceIndicator>
                <Description>H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator</Description>
                <Description languageID="de_DE">H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator</Description>
                <Description languageID="fr_FR">H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator</Description>
                <Description languageID="it_IT">H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator</Description>
                <Description languageID="nl_NL">H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator</Description>
                <Description languageID="en_US">H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator</Description>
                <Note/>
            </ItemMasterHeader>
        </ItemMaster>
    </DataArea>
</SyncItemMaster>
```

**Expected JSON Output:**

```
{ 
   "description":[

      { 
         "languageID":"ge_GE",
         "text":"H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator"
      
},
      { 
         "languageID":"de_DE",
         "text":"H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator"
},
      {
         "languageID":"fr_FR",
         "text":"H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator" 
},
      { 
         "languageID":"it_IT",
         "text":"H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator"    
},
      {
         "languageID":"nl_NL",
         "text":"H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator"
},
      {
         "languageID":"en_US",
         "text":"H3BO3 4% mit Sher Indikator"
}
   
]
}
```

Comment: Also note that part of your input, namely `<BODID>infor-nid:infor:1100::11064973:?ItemMaster&verb=Sync</BODID>` is not well-formed XML, the ampersand needs to be escaped as `<BODID>infor-nid:infor:1100::11064973:?ItemMaster&amp;verb=Sync</BODID>` in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in XSLT 3 you have two options, create the JSON as the corresponding XPath 3.1 maps and arrays (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsG):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="map { 
                'description' : array { 
                  //Description ! 
                  map { 
                    'languageID' : (data(@languageID), 'ge_GE') => head(), 
                    'text' : data() 
                  }
                }
              }"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or transform the XML input to the XML input format the `xml-to-json` functions expects (see intermediary result of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <map>
        <xsl:where-populated>
            <array key="description">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Description"/>
            </array>
        </xsl:where-populated>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Description[not(@languageID)]">
      <map>
          <string key="languageID">ge_GE</string>
          <string key="text">{.}</string>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Description">
      <map>
          <string key="languageID">{@languageID}</string>
          <string key="text">{.}</string>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

) and then use that function `xml-to-json` (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsG/1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
        <map>
            <xsl:where-populated>
                <array key="description">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Description"/>
                </array>
            </xsl:where-populated>
        </map>        
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Description[not(@languageID)]">
      <map>
          <string key="languageID">ge_GE</string>
          <string key="text">{.}</string>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Description">
      <map>
          <string key="languageID">{@languageID}</string>
          <string key="text">{.}</string>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first attempt shown above does not define the order of the JSON property output unless you use a Saxon specific extension attribute. With the second suggestion you could define the order.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this out.

Comment: I am getting a Null JSON as Output.  {  }

Comment: You will need to tell us exactly which code you used and which XSLT processor you used to run the sample.

Comment: I used the second option that you have suggested. First converting it into formatted XML and then into JSON using XSLT. I am performing this operation on Azure Logic Apps.

Comment: @Rushank, do Azure Logic Apps support XSLT 3.0?

Comment: Yes, they do support XSLT, XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 3.0 too. I just tried out again with the first Code you sent. It works for me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Rushank, I am not familiar with how Azure Logic Apps supports XSLT 3 but the difference between the first and the second sample is the serialization method and type of result, the first sample creates an XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 XDM map and (optionally) serializes it as JSON, the second sample outputs JSON, but as plain text. So you might need to postprocess the two stylesheet in your Azure Logic App in a different way or you need to add an additional parsing step in the XSLT, as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsG/2, that way it outputs a JSON object or XDM map as well.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for this additional information. It helps me understand the codes better and work accordingly.